# Disable "Open this link on a phone" feature in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem

Is there a way to disable the QR code feature in the item context menu? Without messing with CSS/JavaScript?

[Open this link on a Phone](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/12/open-this-link-on-phone-new-feature-in-sharepoint-2016.html)